# While running a Js file connection to mongodb is not showing

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, visual-studio-code

“Connected to mongodb database” message is not showing in terminal … how to now if its connected or not? User nme and password are correct than what to do .[enter image description here]

I’m totally a beginner. Please help me with this error

Comment: Please don't use images for code/errors/tracebacks/data/etc. - just copy/paste them into a code block.

Comment: Have you imported it and called the `connectDB()` function anywhere?

Comment: Hi and welcome! As already noted, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you